# Gson json getting the result

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a json string like this:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "http://localhost:2000",
                    "key_fields": "Accountnum",
                    "rows_affected": 0,
                    "last_autoinc": 0
                },
                "Accountnum": "9999999",
                "workphone": null,
                "name": "Smith",
                "address": "33 Main St",
                "city": "Anytown",
                "state": "FL",
                "zip": "33333",

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and I tried to deserialize it according to diffrent questions here on stackoverflow, but I can't get it right.
Here is what I did I created a class, I only need the accountnum and name.

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("Accountnum")
    public String accountnumStr;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String nameStr;    
}
```

I have a string with the json myresult.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Result result = gson.fromJson(myresult,Result.class);
myName.setText(result.nameStr);
```

I receive an empty string.
Thanks

Comment: There is another object outside that contains the allegedly result object in the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visualize your JSON in terms of class objects then it will be no problem at all. Imagine that your root object contains a property named "d" of type "D". And type "D" contains a list of "results" of another type "Result". The result contains its properties as above. Here's the picture of it:

```
class RootObj {
    D d;
}

class D {
    List<Result> results;
}

class Result {
    @SerializedName("Accountnum")
    public String accountnumStr;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String nameStr; 
}
```

To get the objects from a JSON, you would do the following:

```
Gson g = new Gson();    
RootObj ro = g.fromJson(jsonString, RootObj.class);
```

Comment: Ok I made the three class, but how would I retrieve the nameStr.

Comment: The only way I found was ro.d.results.get(0).nameStr, is this the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a object holding the result object your trying to create, you have make the result class an inner class. You're `Result` class would have to look like this:

```
public class ResultParent {

    public class Result {
        @SerializedName("Accountnum")
        public String accountnumStr;

        @SerializedName("name")
        public String nameStr;    
    }
}
```