# How can I convert zxing.result to java.lang.string?

Tags: android-studio, qr-code, zxing

I want to create an app with android studio, which is starts playing sound when gets specified result(for example "play sound") from QR Code. I'm using zxing scanner library. But I get that error:
Zxing.result cannot be applied to java.lang.string.
How can I make this app? Do you have any examples?

Here is the code I used:

```js
public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Log.w("handleResult", result.getText());
        String RS1 = "play sound";
        final MediaPlayer SoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_1);
                if (result.getText(RS1)) {
                SoundMP.start();
                builder.setTitle("Now playing");
                builder.setMessage("sound_1");
                SoundMP.stop();
                mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
            }


    }
```

Comment: Add your code to your question.

Comment: Please put some code first. Just want to know how you had implemented Zxing and how you are getting its result.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried GSON to make it 
there exist already question for that 
[Gson json getting the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044605/gson-json-getting-the-result)

Answer (score 0):

In which line do you get the error?

`result.getText()` should return a String, so the code in your second line should work.

In your fifth line you call `result.getText(RS1)`. I have no idea what `RS1` is, but according to https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/Result.html getText() has no parameters.

Are your trying to compare the text of result to RS1? then you should use `RS1.equals(result.getText())`.

Answer (score -1):

See the docs at: https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/

There you can see that zxing.result has a method "getText()" which returnes a String.